# Mesos master configuration on DC/OS

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am in the process of creating DC/OS cluster on AWS for running Kafka->Spark->Cassandra workloads.

I am interested what is the minimum specification for master node in DC/OS environment. I see that DC/OS suggests m3.xlarge instances, but I do not know why do I need 4 processors and 15GB of RAM, when master is only runnning processes described on: https://docs.mesosphere.com/overview/architecture/ 
-> There is no actual data processing performed by the master.

I would maybe go with m3.large or r3.large instances.

Kindest regards,

Srdjan

Comment: I've been working with DC/OS for a few weeks now, and can confirm that the master is not running very high computation loads so far, although we have not ran any considerable workloads on the cluster yet. Having said that - using suboptimal instances against documentation advice can sometimes waste so much time you's might regret trying to save a few pennies per hour of instance use.

Comment: Also - a closer inspection shows that out of the 15GB the master has in his disposal, 13 are put to use, you might able to compensate for missing memory capacity with swap files, but the default coreos installation I use doesn't have swap enabled.

Comment: @YaronIdan, thank for the reply. I guess we will go for 15GB master as well

Comment: Great, I will add these comments as an answer so you can mark is as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC/OS masters are not used to run any high computation loads, but their memory usage tends to be pretty exhaustive, and so a large instance is recommended.

There might be a way to use smaller instances and compensate for the missing memory using swap files, but straying from the supplier's recommendations should only be done after careful consideration of the potential consequences.